# Identify where a taxonomy term is being used

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, metadata, managed-metadata-service

Is there a way to identify where a particular piece of metadata in the term store is being used on a particular site and in how many instances it is used.

So the user has a need to identify whether a particular term is being used before it can be deleted.